# Batch to python opening chrome

Tags: python, batch-file

I'm trying to convert this code into Python; anyone able to help real quickly?

```
start "Chrome" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="Profile 12"
start "webpage name" "https://www.google.com"

TIMEOUT 3

start "Chrome" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="Profile 12" --incognito "https://www.google.com"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
import webbrowser
import time
url = 'www.google.com'
chrome_path1 = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s --profile-directory="Profile 12"'
webbrowser.get(chrome_path1).open_new(url)
time.sleep(3)
chrome_path2 = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s --incognito'
webbrowser.get(chrome_path2).open_new(url)
```

Comment: im trying to open chrome on a profile normally + another one in incognito mode

Comment: Updated.  Have a look